# Point detection and circle area selection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with a particular type of images. Those, after obtaining the spectrum (aply the fft), I obtain the following picture:

[image]

So I want to select one of those "points" (called orders of the spectrum), at the following way:

[image]

I mean "draw" a circle aroud it, select the pixels inside and then center those pixels(without the "border circle"):

[image]

How can I perform it using OpenCV? Does exist any function?

Comment: Which of the points in particular? The highest peak?

Comment: "Yes and no". I selected the highest peak because of the minmaxLoc function. But I have to be able to select one of those "automatically"  and then center.

Comment: So you want to redraw the image, with the selected peak/point at the centre?  I.e. crop out the rest?

Comment: is your question how to find/select the "points" or how to select the region around one already found point?

Comment: @PokeyMcPokerson exactly! Thank you for making my question simpler!

Comment: @Micka the specific question is "selection" but maybe you know any function to mind the "two highest peaks" it would be very useful

Comment: For finding the peaks: Maybe first threshold (Otsu?), and then use hough circles or contours to find resulting circles...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: As per discussion below, to 'select' a circle, a mask can be used:

```python
# Build mask
mask = np.zeros(image_array.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask, max_loc, circle_radius, (255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0)

# Apply mask (using bitwise & operator)
result_array = image_array & mask

# Crop/center result (assuming max_loc is of the form (x, y))
result_array = result_array[max_loc[1] - circle_radius:max_loc[1] + circle_radius,
                            max_loc[0] - circle_radius:max_loc[0] + circle_radius, :]
```

This leaves me with something like:

[image: Masked and cropped image]

Another edit:
[This](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_blob.html#example-plot-blob-py) might be useful for finding your peaks.

Comment: The problem is that I want to "select a circle" instead of a "box"

Comment: Images are always rectangular, so what do you mean by "selecting"? In general its mostly done by drawing al filled white circle on black background and use that as a mask for copying or processing pixel.

Comment: Yes, I need to crop that "circular region" and then center it. But I dont know how to accomplish it, because my idea was to use the bitwise and operator but I can't define an appropiate "mask". I was thinking in 'roi = np.zeros(image.shape);cv2.circle(roi, max_loc, 50, 255, -1, 8, 0); cv2.bitwise_and(nodcterm, nodcterm, mask=roi)' but I get an error: error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1035: error: (-215) (mask.type() == CV_8UC1 || mask.type() == CV_8SC1) in function binary_op

Comment: Try make the mask 8-bit by creating it with `roi = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)` or something similar.

Comment: I couldn't get the bitwise_and function to work so I did it the numpy way (see the updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you asked, but if you just want to center around such a point, you can do it with subregions:

```
cv::Point center(yourCenterX_FromLeft, yourCenterY_fromTop);
int nWidth = yourDesiredWidthAfterCentering;  // or 2* circle radius
int nHeight= yourDesiredHeightAfterCentering; // or 2* circle radius

// specify the subregion: top-left position and width/height
cv::Rect subImage = cv::Rect(center.x-nWidth/2, center.y-nHeight/2, nWidth, nHeight);

// extract the subregion out of the original image. remark that no data is copied but original data is referenced
cv::Mat subImageCentered = originalImage(subImage);

cv::imshow("subimage", subImageCentered);
```

didnt test, but that should be ok.

EDIT: sorry, it's c++ but I think subregions will work similar in python?!?